# I am getting the speed by gps using phonegap in android but how can I calculate the average and maximum speed from this value?

Tags: android, cordova, gps, phonegap-build

I am getting the speed by gps using phonegap in android but how can I calculate the average and maximum speed from this value?

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    var speedO= position.coords.speed

      var Rspeed= (speedO*(60*60))/1000 //Calculate speed from meter per second to km per hour.
      var Nspeed = parseFloat(Math.round(Rspeed * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);




        $("#speed").html("Nspeed");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do simple arithmetic.

```
average = (sum of values) / number of values
```

So you will need some sort of data structure to hold each of the speeds that you record and then be able to add them up and divide by the number that you've collected.

To get the max speed, you have to start with a max speed of zero in a variable. Then:

```
max speed = 0
if current speed > max speed
    max speed = current speed
```